# como desabilitar la ruta register laravel jetstream?

Tags: laravel

quisiera desactivar la ruta por defecto para crear nuevos usuarios,quiero evitar,que los usuarios puedan crear sus propias cuentas , por lo cual,quiero desactivar esta ruta, como lo podría hacer?

Intente con : Auth::routes(["register" => false]);

Pero me indica el siguiente error :

In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.

Me pide instalar laravel/ui pero yo estoy usando laravel jetstream,hay alguna alternativa para este? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que jetstream usa fortify, si es así podrías desactivar el register en la configuración de fortify

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Gracias por la recomendacion,,fui a la configuracion de fortify y comente la linea :    Features::registration(), y me funciono!, desconozco si es la mejor forma pero era lo que necesitaba!

Comment: Sí, a eso me refería. No he usado jetstream, pero sí fortify. Podes leer más en la doc https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#fortify-features y basándote en eso escribir una respuesta

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Quisiera hacerte una pregunta no relacionado al tema,como puedo enviar un link con la direccion de la parte deseada, como lo haz hecho tu?,independientemente de la pagina